# Contact groups in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I like to send mails to groups that I created. I used to readily see the groups each time I went to my contacts. I don't know what has happened, for a few days now, I can't see the list of group contacts, although if I remember a group name and search it, it appears. What went wrong? What do I do for the group list to appear in the contacts again?

Answer (score 2):

You mean you don’t see the groups in the left-side menu/column? If that’s the case, beside *My Contacts*, at the left, there is a small arrow—click on it.

[image]     [image]